# How to get values out of Json that is in a string variable using Java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON string inside a string variable like this:

```
   [{"user_id":"123","email":"person@email.com","lat":"40.748329","lng":"-73.996223",
                    "first_name":"Alex","last_name":"Genadinik"}]
```

Is there a way to just very quickly extract all the values using java? While googleing, I am running into very bulky and code-heavy examples that makes me think there must be a simpler way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), it is a very simple google API